# Is it correct to say, "This dress attracts me the most?"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Is it right to say, "This dress attracts me **the most**"?

If this sentence is wrong, with what words it will be right?
When should I use the word 'the most'?

Comment: Depends on what you want to say. What *do* you want to say?

Comment: Hello,Martha. For example: 'among all the books I like this one the most'. Or, 'This grammar rule confuses me the most '. Is it right to use 'the most' in these cases and in the end of a sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the bolded part of your sentence. "Attracts", however, is not generally used in such an active sense when talking about an inanimate object, such as a dress.

> I find this dress to be the most attractive [of the ones displayed].

(As with any comparative/superlative, "the most" is meaningful only if you define the domain, either explicitly or by context. Thus, if you've already established what dresses you're comparing, then you don't need the part in square brackets.)

If you want to end the sentence with "the most", then you need a different verb.

> Of the dresses I've tried on today, I think this one flatters my figure the most.
>
> Among all the books I've read, I like this one the most.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to say *this dress attracts me the most.* You would use *the most** here to mean that no any other dress is as attractive as this one. **The most** suggests the superlative degree and is only one in that context.